# Filtering a list crashes without throwing an error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, youtube-api, filtering

I have this google-apps-script code, to get a few YT channels, and filter some of them:

```
    var popularChannels = YouTube.Channels.list('id, snippet, statistics', {
        id: resultsParentChannelIds.slice(i * 50, (i + 1) * 50)
    }).getItems().
    filter(
      ch => 
    ((channelIdFilter == "" || ch.id == channelIdFilter)
    && (subCountFilter == "" || ch.statistics.subscriberCount > subCountFilter)
    && (channelLocationFilter == "" || channel.snippet.country == undefined || channel.snippet.country == channelLocationFilter)
    && (channelNegativeLocationFilter == "" || channel.snippet.country == undefined || channel.snippet.country != channelNegativeLocationFilter)));
```

All filters are `""` besides the last NegativeLocation filter.

But the debugger stops after the first filter without writing any error.

How can I debug this or understand what's the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed the currentValue variable from `ch` to `channel` part way through.

```
var popularChannels = YouTube.Channels.list('id, snippet, statistics', {
  id: resultsParentChannelIds.slice(i * 50, (i + 1) * 50)
}).getItems().
filter(
ch => 
((channelIdFilter == "" || ch.id == channelIdFilter)
&& (subCountFilter == "" || ch.statistics.subscriberCount > subCountFilter)
&& (channelLocationFilter == "" || ch.snippet.country == undefined || ch.snippet.country == channelLocationFilter)
&& (channelNegativeLocationFilter == "" || ch.snippet.country == undefined || ch.snippet.country != channelNegativeLocationFilter)));
```